# Building error in eclipse

Tags: java, android

I am working on android application and getting an error that "apk file can not be build".
This error occurred when I was exporting an apk file.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'CVCamera'.
The file does not exist for the external tool named Native Builder.
The file does not exist for the external tool named Native Builder.
```

Answer (score 0):

deleting the R.Java file in /Gen folder did the trick for me

In my case this problem started after eclipse updated the plugin with the v4.0 API release. I fixed it by going to the main preferences for Eclipse and under Android->Build uncheck 'Skip packaging and dexing until export or launch'